# Abandoning high ranking website but using URL for SEO benefits

Tags: seo, url, ecommerce, marketing, prestashop

I have two websites. A pet products (e.g. `petsite.com`) website and a dog products (e.g. `dogsite.com`) website.  Petsite runs on Prestashop and Dogsite runs on EKMPowershop.  All the goods sold on Dogsite we already sell on Petsite but Dogsite ranks much higher on Google for dog specific keywords; we, however, get more sales overall on Petsite due to the extensive email marketing that we do for it.

We'd like to abandon Dogsite completely and focus our efforts on Petsite. Is there any way we could take advantage of the SEO benefits gained from the `dogsite.com` URL and use it for the dog products category within the `petsite.com` website? Maybe using URL redirects, URL cloaking or some other method?

So maybe if someone clicks on `dogsite.com`, they are taken to `petsite.com/dogs` instead? Would my Google ranking for the URL be negatively affected by the redirect?

Help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [301 redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) from `dogsite.com` to `petsite.com/dogs` as discussed [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).

Then follow this:  [Tell Google when your site moves](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)

For more helpful information, see this: [Google Webmaster Blog - Best practices when moving your site](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/best-practices-when-moving-your-site.html).

If the content is going to be transferred to the new site, your rankings may dip for a while, but should return once Google builds trust for your new domain (providing that there isn't new competition for your keywords, or the other normal factors faced with SEO).

**Update:** 
If the content is not going to be transferred (because it's generated by different e-commerce platforms or otherwise), then you would not maintain the same rankings. You would have to develop the same quality of content that resulted in `dogsite.com's` keyword rankings, and SEO marketing, in hopes that it would rank as well.